# Is color saturation really related to light intensity?

Tags: color, color-science, color-management, colorspace

In [this article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorfulness) on Wikipedia, under saturation, it's written that "The purest (most saturated) color is achieved by using just one wavelength at a high intensity, such as in laser light. If the intensity drops, then as a result the saturation drops"

I don't get the relation between light intensity and saturation. From what I know, saturation is the chromatic intensity for a given brightness or lightness, and is roughly related to the excitation purity of the light. In which case, just having a single wavelength or small band of wavelengths should render a color fully saturated.

Looked into this in the book "Color Appearance Models" by Mark Fairchild, where I found: "For given viewing conditions and at luminance levels within the range of photopic vision, a color stimulus of a given chromaticity exhibits approximately constant saturation for all luminance levels, except when brightness is very high."

Am I missing something?